# laravel problem with chatify doesn't display user name

Tags: laravel

i'm trying to use chatify on my project
in messager page it show always the name Chatify Messenger
i want to display the user name who im talking with
how to do this
btw my user table doesn't have name column
it have fname and lname
so what i should change to display user fname or lname

user table : https://ibb.co/CKTw1TZ
chatify view : https://ibb.co/F7MJqNQ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "Chatify Messenger" to fname or lname